# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Pair < Boolean, Integer > result) {
    Log.d("XXX", "Result : " + result.second);
    if (isCancelled())
        return;

    if (result.second > 0)
        nextPage();
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (result.first)
        notifyMayHaveMorePages();
    else
        notifyNoMorePages();

};
```

I am getting the following exception...

> 05-02 12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-02 12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034225, class
>   com.greenway.primemobile.common.SectionedListView) with Adapter(class
>   android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)] 05-02 12:34:16.423:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4042)
>   05-02 12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>   05-02 12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>   05-02 12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-02 12:34:16.423:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-02 12:34:16.423:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-02 12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 05-02
>   12:34:16.423: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2):

If you change any content in the adapter you need to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` for the adapter then

Answer (score 2):

I know its a late reply....but i just got this error recently .... I was using [android-amazing-listview](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/source/checkout). And I am getting the same error ended with

```
(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]).
```

**Solution that work for me is->**

I think this issues stems from the fact that `getAdapter` is returning the `AmazingAdapter` instead of the wrapped `HeaderListViewAdapter` causing a difference in count at times. I simply removed the getAdapter method from AmazingListView and haven't got the exception since.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the UI inside the runonui thread as like below

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() 
{
    //Update UI here                        
}
});
```